# Function parameter life time

Tags: c++

I though that after function call all rvalue parameters send to function will be destroyed. I'm completely messed up with this example. Can someone help me with it? Maybe some links where it explained.

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(const char* name)
        : ptr(nullptr)
    {
        ptr = name;
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        system("PAUSE");
    }

    const char* ptr;
};

int main()
{
    Test t("Hello");
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand what your problem is. And this is not c

Comment: In short, the life of arguement ends at the same time the function call ends.

Comment: What output do you expect ? What is the proiblem ?

Comment: @Sean83 So "Hello" is destroyed when the constructor finishes? Nope!

Comment: Shoud've been parameter instead of argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"Hello"` is a string literal. The string is a basic value that has static lifetime. Same as `42`: that number is never destroyed.

---

In other news:

- Initializing `ptr` to null, and a nanosecond later assigning to it, is perplexing and can therefore waste some programmer's time. Just initialize it to the value it should have.
- Pausing a program at the end serves no purpose and can be a practical problem, so just don't. To see the program's output when you run it from some IDE, use the appropriate way to run it. E.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in Visual Studio.
- It's generally a good idea to adopt some special naming conventions for data members. E.g., `ptr_`, or `my_ptr`, or `myPtr`, or `mPtr` (I prefer the first). However, don't use `_ptr`, as some beginners do, because that conflicts with a convention used to keep C and C++ implementation global names separate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know of basic value static lifetime.